How Do i Make A Random Button In React
const button = ['Home', 'Support'];
function FavoriteColor() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>My favorite color is {color}!</h1>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setColor = {button}}
      >{button[genRandomInt(1)]}</button>
    </>
  )
}
function genRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
}

how do i make the button to change into something random and output in the Favoritecolor function ? in setcolor i just started learning react so pls be patient with me :))

What do you expect setColor = {button} to do?

Even while writing an answer, I get stuck at the part where you're trying to update your "favorite color" from "red" to either "Home" or "Support".  It's not clear to me what the intended functionality is here.  At best that attempt to assign to setColor is a typo, but after that it's not clear what the logic should be doing...

I chngaed it to my favorite color is {button} still nothing

So I want 1 random button :)) that's all

The most immediate problem here is this:
setColor = {button}

Because:

You can't assign a new value to a const
setColor is a function, you'd call that function and pass a value to it
The object {button} is almost certainly not what you want to set your state value to

You can correct the first two structural problems by simply calling the function:
setColor(button);

However, the logical problem remains.  Setting the color state to the button array (which really should be a plural name...) doesn't do anything useful.  Presumably you want it to be a random selection from the array?  Note that you're already randomly selecting a value here:
{button[genRandomInt(1)]}

It's not clear what logic you're trying to implement or if/how you want these things corrected.  But what you've indicated in a comment on the question above is:

So I want 1 random button :)) that's all

In which case you can simply make the selection random:
return (
  <>
    <h1>My favorite color is {color}!</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick={() => setColor(button[genRandomInt(1)])}>
      {button[genRandomInt(1)]}
    </button>
  </>
);

Note how the text of the button is still random:
{button[genRandomInt(1)]}

And now we're using that same randomness when selecting a value for updating state:
setColor(button[genRandomInt(1)])

Note that this does not guarantee that the two random selections will be the same.  Nor does it even guarantee that any given selection is going to be different from the previous selection.  (And this answer does nothing to address the confusing logic in which you change your "favorite color" from "red" to either "Home" or "Support"...)
It does guarantee that when you click the button a random selection will be chosen, which is the stated goal here.

Thanks for you pacient and i saw that it's how you discribe to be !
